# Store Output of a for loop in python to a dataframe column without append

Tags: python

I am generating random alphanumeric strings using below code

```
import random
import string
import secrets
num = 10 

res = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+ string.digits) for x in range(num))
print("Secure random string is :"+ str(res))
```

Secure random string is :W8W602HOMJ

Now I am trying to Generate N Number of this random strings using for loop, Below are the two variations i have used.

```
import random
import string
import secrets
num = 10 # define the length of the string
N=10
for i in range (1,N):

    res = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+ string.digits) for x in range(num))
    df3.append(res)
print(df3)
```

Error : append is being Depecrted use pd.concat and 'Str' cant be appended to Dataframe.

```
for i in range (1,N):

    res = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+ string.digits) for x in range(num))
    df3 = pd.concat(df3,res)
print(df3)
```

Error : FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of concat except for the argument 'objs' will be keyword-only.

please help me here.

Comment: `append()` expects a dataframe or dict-like object. If you know the column name, use `df3.append({column_name: res}, ignore_index=True)`.

Comment: python is not supporting append, its throwing future warning to use concat